# Spresenseから音を出す方法について

Tags: spresense

Spresenseにスピーカーを接続し音を出す方法について

Spresense拡張ボードのJP8とJP9にスピーカーを接続し音を再生させたいです。

arduino-SDK環境で、実施を考えていますが、拡張ボードのJP8とJP9から
スピーカーから音を再生させるにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

公式の方法ではないですが、手軽にやるには **R15,R16,R17,R18 をショートしてしまう**という手が使えますよ。すでにやられている方がいるので参考にされてみるといいかも知れません。

**SpresenseでLチカから始める (28) ハイレゾの再生V1.1.2**
https://www.denshi.club/cookbook/arduino/spresense/spresensel-7-v112.html

Comment: そんな手軽な方法があるのですね

Answer (score 0):

スピーカーの使用方法はこちらに載ってましたよ。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/hw_docs_ja.html#_HOW_TO_USE_SPEAKERS
メインボードの改修作業が要るようです。

(以下、マニュアルから抜粋)

> メインボードは出荷時は拡張ボードのヘッドホン出力に合わせた設定になっています。スピーカーを使用するにはメインボード上のチップ部品の載せ替えはんだ付け作業と、拡張ボードへのはんだ付け作業が必要です。 ここでの作業は小型部品のはんだ付けや基板の改造を伴いますので、適切なスキル及び機材をもっている方のみ実施するように注意してください。
> ここに記載のはんだ作業を行った場合には、いかなる場合であっても製品保証の対象外となります。ご自身の責任において実施してください。